# Setting up Subl handler with Sublime Text

Tags: macos, sublimetext2

Hi I am trying to set up the subl handler for *Sublime Text 2*

I found this on Github
https://github.com/asuth/subl-handler

I downloaded it and ran it, which opened XCode. I am seeing an issue in XCode but I'm not sure if that affects things. When I try using the example test in Terminal the file doesn't open in Sublime Text.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to open `subl://` URLs in Sublime Text, or just get `subl` working on the command line so you can open files in ST from Terminal?

Comment: I was hoping to achieve both, but my main use case would be to open URLs from stack traces from the web apps I'm building.

Comment: Why does it open xcode? Do you have the xcode command line tools enabled?

Comment: I guess, although I have no idea why that is so.

Comment: " I am seeing an issue in XCode but I'm not sure if that affects things" - perhaps post this issue.